# Need directions for hosting my Blazor Server App+Class Library+SQL Database to IIS on VM running Windows Server 2019

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, blazor

So my Project solution is made up of,

1. My Blazor Server App .NET 6(Has project reference dependencies to the class library and server project
2. My Server SQL Server 2019 database project which has all my Stored Procedures and Table scripts.
3. My .NET Class Library

I already have a windows server 2019 machine and I need some sort of direction to point me to how to set it all up.

1. I know I need to publish my Blazor Server App and publish it on IIS.
2. However how do I publish the Class Library together with the app?
3. How should I publish my database? Do I have to install Visual Studio on my Windows Server and then publish the database to MSQL using visual studio via the project?

I feel like I have some sort of idea but I would like some guidance or affirmation if I am doing things the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying Blazor Server App:

1. Publish the Blazor Server App:
2. Right-click on your Blazor Server project in Visual Studio.
3. Select "Publish."
4. Choose the appropriate publish target, which could be a folder or directly to IIS.
5. Configure the publishing settings (connection strings, deployment mode, etc.).
6. Publish the application.
7. Setting up IIS:
8. Install IIS on your Windows Server 2019 machine.
9. Create a new website in IIS or use the default one.
10. Copy the published content of your Blazor Server App to the IIS site directory.
11. Configure Application Pool:
12. Ensure that the application pool for your website is set to use the correct .NET runtime version (in this case, .NET 6).

Deploying Class Library:

1. Include Class Library in Blazor Server App:

   - Make sure your Blazor Server project references the Class Library project.
   - When you publish your Blazor Server App, the necessary DLLs from the Class Library should be included.

Deploying SQL Server Database:

1. Publish SQL Server Database:

   - In Visual Studio, right-click on your SQL Server database project.
   - Select "Publish."
   - Configure the target database connection and other settings.
   - Publish the database project to your SQL Server instance.
2. Database Connection in Blazor Server App:

   - Ensure that your Blazor Server App's configuration points to the correct database connection string. This is usually done in the `appsettings.json` file.